# Command line tool to generate memorable passwords?

Tags: linux, security, passwords, password-generation

I’m looking for a tool, command line or GUI, for Linux that generates memorable passwords.

An equivalent of what I am looking for would be passwords that the Mac OS X keychain can generate, something like `apples12$/fourteen`. Something strong, but easily memorized by a user.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've since moved on to [XCKD style passphrases](http://xkcd.com/936/) for most of my passwords. Here is a 1 liner from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8990/generate-an-xkcd-936-style-4-word-password) to generate a passphrase:

```
shuf -n4 /usr/share/dict/words | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: actually, there is an issue with this one-liner: it may use words like "the", "them", "their" and "moat", "iris", "he". Do you see the problem? There's an overlap between prefixes and suffixes, which reduces the actual entropy of the generated password and can lead to pretty weak passwords if the strings are not long enough (especially with 4 words). This is why word-based password generators use crafted word lists. Granted, passwords generated with the above are pretty good: 14 chars minimum in my tests, with a median size of 34. But their entropy is not reliable.

Comment: What is the the issue with having overlapping prefixes / suffixes? I can understand your point about length, but you'll need to explain the other point.

Comment: let's simplify to the extreme. you have a dictionnary made out of three words: `the`, `me` and `theme`. normally, you would expect you'd have the entropy equally from those three words, but in this case, you can't count `theme` because it is a combination of the other two words. in effect, `theme` actually adds zero entropy to the password.

Comment: But isn't "the me" distinct from "theme"? I get that possible letters add entropy but this approach is more about the size of passwords. I don't get how "the me theme" would be easier to guess then a sequence with no overlapping characters like "do ray music"

Comment: `the me` isn't distinct from `theme` because you do not separate the words with spaces. the number of letters adds a certain amount of entropy, assuming that the attacker doesn't know how you generate your password. you can't assume that, especially if you publicly post about it. in that case, you must compute how much each word from the dictionary contributes to the entropy, and that's a different algorithm. as i mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1246245/177019), i wrote a detailed article about how to evaluate that...

Comment: I like to use words of medium length that aren't obscure. So here's my variation of the answer: `curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-medium.txt" | shuf -n4 | tr -d '\n'`. It requires you to be online to download the word list but the password generation itself is offline.

Comment: @anarcat I'd like to read your answer. I appreciate the other info you've provided so far. Will check out xkcdpass.

Comment: @wbg my answer is here https://superuser.com/a/1246245/177019

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend people stop using pwgen - its main interested was generating "human-rememberable passwords", but it showed multiple vulnerabilities in doing exactly that. And using it to generate completely random strings isn't that useful either.

I wrote a [detailed article](https://anarc.at/blog/2017-02-18-passwords-entropy/) on that very topic, but basically, the gist of it is to use the [diceware](https://github.com/ulif/diceware) program (or, if you like dice, the actual [diceware system](http://diceware.com/)) or [xkcdpass](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xkcdpass/). To generate strong memorable passwords, I generally use diceware with the following configuration file:

```
[diceware]
caps = off
delimiter = "-"
wordlist = en_eff
```

Examples:

```
$ diceware
turkey-eligibly-underwire-recite-lifter-wasp
$ diceware
lend-rubdown-cornflake-tint-shawl-ozone
$ diceware
syndrome-ramp-cresting-resolved-flinch-veneering
$ diceware
alto-badass-eclipse-surplus-rudder-quit
```

I turn off caps and spaces because they generate distinct audible noises that could be leveraged by an attacker. The `-` delimiter is a lesser evil: it would be better to not use any separator and the `en_eff` wordlist is especially crafted for that purpose. But I find it easier to communicate and share passwords when they have *some* separator.

To generate a completely random password, I use the following shell function:

```
# secure password generator or, as dkg puts it:
# high-entropy compact printable/transferable string generator
# a password generator would be pwqgen or diceware
pwg() {
    ENTROPY=${1:-20} # in bytes
    # strip possible newlines if output is wrapped and trailing = signs as they add nothing to the password's entropy
    head -c $ENTROPY /dev/random | base64 | tr -d '\n='
    echo
}
```

I mention this because I believe it is important to memorize *less* passwords and instead rely on a password manager to store large strings that are hard to guess. More details about the rationale behind those choices is explained in the aforementioned article and my [password managers review](https://anarc.at/blog/2017-02-22-password-managers/).

Answer (score 12):

> *2020: I posted this answer in 2011. In the years that have passed, the face of cyber security and the demands to it have changed rapidly and enormously. As has been pointed out by anarcat, pwgen may not (or no longer) be suitable for securing high-security systems. He sets out to describe the technical details on how pwgen can, in some circumstances, use insecure methods of password derivation from available entropy in [his article](https://anarc.at/blog/2017-02-18-passwords-entropy/). Although I no longer believe in generating passwords to then try and remember them myself, I do not have the technical aptitude to validate, let alone vouch for the contents of the article as quoted so please read it and draw your own conclusions. Having said that, I am convinced that pwgen will suffice for low-security systems where attack is very unlikely.*

You might want to check out the `pwgen` application. I know it to be available in the Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian and Suse repositories.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen):

> The pwgen program generates passwords
>   which are designed to be easily
>   memorized by humans, while being as
>   secure as possible. Human-memorable
>   passwords are never going to be as
>   secure as completely completely random
>   passwords. In particular, passwords
>   generated by pwgen without the -s
>   option should not be used in places
>   where the password could be attacked
>   via an off-line brute-force attack. On
>   the other hand, completely randomly
>   generated passwords have a tendency to
>   be written down, and are subject to
>   being compromised in that fashion.
>
> The pwgen program is designed to be
>   used both interactively, and in shell
>   scripts. Hence, its default behavior
>   differs depending on whether the
>   standard output is a tty device or a
>   pipe to another program. Used
>   interactively, pwgen will display a
>   screenful of passwords, allowing the
>   user to pick a single password, and
>   then quickly erase the screen. This
>   prevents someone from being able to
>   "shoulder surf" the user's chosen
>   password.

Comment: Passwords like 'Zei7jool' or 'Oowee6ei' don't seem very memorable to me. Perhaps I am missing a flag?

Comment: @James They are generated according to an algorithm that puts letters in a non-sense, yet because they are logical in human linguistics, rememberable order. You'll probably have to make a similar effort to remember the `apples12$/fourteen` password. Just give it a try.

Comment: It spews out a giant list of passwords, just choose the most memorable -- there are some gems in there ;-)

Comment: pwgen passwords have serious security issues by default, and are not very memorable. use diceware or xkcdpass instead.

Comment: @anarcat, what are the serious issues that you mentioned? Please add some more details.

Comment: as i said in an answer here and a comment above, see https://anarc.at/blog/2017-02-18-passwords-entropy/

Comment: @anarcat thanks! I agree pwgen may not be the best option (anymore) but I will leave my answer with the disclaimer I added to address your concerns in place for historical purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Try 'gpw'. It produces passwords such as these:
ubsonsin
morimplo
demenump
esselymn
kidentst
anenterg
essonsuf
iesssssi
bestruss
tnestese

Description: Trigraph Password Generator
 This package generates pronounceable passwords. It uses the statistics of
 three-letter combinations (trigraphs) taken from whatever dictionaries you 
 feed it.
 Thus pronounceability may differ from language to language. Based
 on the ideas in Morrie Gasser's password generator for Multics, and Dan
 Edwards's generator for CTSS.  FIPS Standard 181 describes a similar
 digraph-based generator, derived from Gasser's.

Answer (score 2):

A good option that has popped up since I asked this is [Redacted's XKCD-password-generator](https://github.com/redacted/XKCD-password-generator).

It's a nice Python script to generate XKCD style passwords that has some advance options like acrostic support.

Answer (score 1):

You could try install openssl

`openssl rand -base64 12` or `openssl rand -hex 12`

Kudos to [400 the cat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306107/501487) where he makes
reference to the above example.

If thats not good enough, perhaps try:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~' </dev/urandom | head -c 43 ; echo
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the answer from James McMahon and it's comments, here is a one-liner containing word-length restriction and word concatenation using `paste`.

`curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-medium.txt" | grep -E '^.{4,6}$' | shuf -n4 | paste -sd '.,-'`

- `grep -E '^.{4,6}$'` filter words being 4 to 6 characters long
- `shuf -n4` take 4 at random
- `paste -sd '.,-'` join all words by cycling through, in this case, `.,-`

Answer (score 0):

> [`sf-pwgen`](https://github.com/anders/pwgen) is a command line tool which generates passwords using the SecurityFoundation framework in OS X.